# John Deere x738 mower stopped working suddenly

Tags: troubleshooting, lawnmower, john-deere

My JD X738 only has 33 hours on it. I was mowing the other day just fine & suddenly the mower part quit & the steering became difficult and stiff. I drove it into the garage to check it out. Hydraulic fluid, Engine Oil, & Coolant levels were all normal. I then restarted the engine with no problem, however the mower won't engage, i can't raise the mower the the hydraulic lever, and i can not move the machine forward or backwards.  The only things that work are the engine , instument panel, and headlights.  The problem seems to be hydraulic in nature. Dealer says they are running 3-4 weeks behind.

Comment: There may be a drive belt for the transmission and hydraulics, see if it is broken.

Comment: What year is your mower? Looking online, it has a 4-year/700-hour bumper-to-bumper warranty. If it's a 2014 or newer, take it back to JD and have them fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your hydraulic pump problem quit as mine did in my 1023 the answer the dealer said was not used much I only have 11 hours on it it’s 3 years old.My relatives have old subcompact tractors and have let them sit for 6-8 months and never had this problem. I feel it’s a factory defective part the dealer just does not want to admit it. Thanks Mark